# Which microcontroller for a program with many floating point operations

Tags: stm32

I'm using the STM32 uC for quite a long time, from F1,F2,F3,F4 to F7. In one application I changed from the F4 (100 MHz) to the F7 (200 MHz), but this seems like it was a mistake.

The application run on the F4 with around 15kHz, on the F7 with around 12 kHz, although the F7 runs on double the clock speed. So it seems, that the two processors have different FPU architectures and as I read, the F4 has some parallelism for the FPU while the F7 can only do sequential operation.

So is it true, that for an application with heavy FPU load, an F4 outperforms an F7?

**Edit:**

So I made some measurements on real hardware to verify my toughts:

**Hardware:** STM32F722RC vs STM32F412CE

**Programm:** Just some FPU operations as used in my application

```
  for(uint16_t i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
  {
      if(x > 6)
      {
          x = 0.1f;
      } else if (x < -6)
      {
          x = -0.1f;
      }
      x = x + 0.05f;
      x = x + sinf(x)*cosf(x);
  }

  cyclic_time[ptr] = htim6.Instance->CNT;
  cyclic_time[ptr] /= 1e6f;
  ptr++;
  if(ptr >= 20)
  {
      ptr = 0;
  }
  htim6.Instance->CNT=0;
```

**Performance F4:**
[image]

At 100Mhz:
[image]

--> So an average cycle time of around 7.365ms

**Performance F7:**
[image]

At 200Mhz:
[image]

At 100Mhz:
[image]

--> So an average cycle time of around 9.954ms @ 200Mhz best case (I verified, that in both cases the timer runs on the correct clock speed, 100Mhz and 99 Prescaler, such that the measurement is correct)

So that is exactly what I observed in my real application. Somehow the F4 outperformance the F7 when it comes to floating point operations.

**Edit2:**

Compiler Options F4:
[image]

Compiler Options F7:
[image]

**Edit3:**
To ensure, that the optimizer is not a problem, I tested the cycle time with the optimizer enabled on speed:

**F4:**
[image]
--> Around 6.44ms

**F7:**
[image]
--> Around 8.344ms

So this leads to the same problem.

Projects for F4 and F7:
http://www.mediafire.com/file/lljhgsez4xk9vat/Test_Projects.rar/file

Comment: hm, on a modern compiler, I'd assume the complete `for` loop would get compiled away and replaced with a constant assignment. Also, don't underestimate how complicated `sinf`/`cosf` are: depending on your math lib, this might mostly be control flow or soft floating point operations!

Comment: I turned off the optimization for the compiler and I use the standard generated settings from a CubeMX export for both uC

Comment: Does that make sense, though? Instead of buying a more expensive microcontroller, you'd turn on optimizations first. Comparing unoptimized code is kind of unfair, especially on a RISC architecture.

Comment: I turn on optimized for speed normally, but this test is just to compare the overal speed for basic operations. When I turn on the optimizer for speed, both get way faster, but still the F4 outperforms the F7

Comment: yes, but if your compiler produces code that isn't optimal for a CPU, is it then the CPU's fault it's slow?

Comment: No, but I want to see if it is the compiler or some hardware options or maybe even the architecture

Comment: Fair point! So, I'm playing around with the godbolt compiler explorer, here's a link for you to have fun: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Cb4saQ

Comment: also, I'm not sure which clock source TIM6 uses?

Comment: TIM6 uses APB1, I tested it also with APB2 on 100Mhz to verify, still the same.

Comment: darn! You're so thorough, I'm starting to doubt my judgement! (which means you're clearly doing good work, thank you for asking such a great question! And I might simply be wrong.) so, are you as excited as me? Next thing I'd do is use `objdump -D -S` on the object (.o) files produced by your `gcc -c` calls and compare them (e.g. with `diff`)

Comment: I uploaded both projects with the compiled files here: http://www.mediafire.com/file/lljhgsez4xk9vat/Test_Projects.rar/file I need to go now and will to the disassembly later. I really don't know what this could cause, but it seems not to be the compiler.

Comment: In case it helps: disassembly: https://gist.github.com/marcusmueller/a4e462aa326a073fae6039a254396a2d

Answer (score 2):

Hm, until you do a bit of benchmarking to show that it's really the FPU, I'd heavily doubt this is about the Cortex-M7F FPU being slower (it's really not, never seen that).

Generally, try to make sure you're not inadvertedly doing something like soft-Floating Point math (`-mfloat-abi=soft`), or aren't using math libraries that have been optimized for the STM32F4, but not the F7. Make sure you're compiling for ARMv7-M or ARMv7EM.

The fact that you're putting a processing rate to this: This sounds like a DSP workload. So, make sure you're really using the DSP instructions: both the M4 and the M7 should have single-cycle Multiply-accumulates, so a 200 MHz M7 should in any case be twice as fast as a 100 MHz M4 if these are used. Your compiler should infer these, but sometimes a bit of hand-assembly pays.

So, either you're using a compiler too old or set to not use the FPU, DSP instructions sensibly, or something else is going on here.

---

From a general DSP engineering perspective: often, there's much to solve in algorithmically or programming inefficiencies before specific properties of FPUs become relevant for application performance. Since already your 100 MHz Cortex-M4F is a pretty strong processor, 15 kS/s of throughput does sound like a pretty hefty DSP workload (700 CPU cycles per sample!) and it might really make sense to ask a question on the [DSP StackExchange](https://dsp.stackexchange.com) sister site, describing the algorithm you're doing, and specifically about how to do it.

Comment: You should delete "-mfloat-abi=soft" part. It is not about the library, it is about the calling convention.

Comment: @Ayhan it's about both. If you're using `soft`, then gcc will produce software calls for every floating point operation (`__eabi_fadd` and so on).

Comment: If you didn't force the library, it might choose the compatible one. That is about how the precompiled library was compiled before. One additional version of the hard fp library could be compiled with soft-abi option, so it would be more universal in the expense of some performance. My compiler environment has only one version, so when I try to compile with forcing the library, linker complies like this: "libgcc.a uses VFP register arguments, main.elf does not".